# Derivative of autoencoder

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

### Problem

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{W}} \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{W})=\frac{1}{2}\Vert \mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{Wx} - \mathbf{x}\Vert_2 ^2$$
where $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\ (m < n)$.

### What I Have Done

The gradient of $\mathcal{L}$ is influenced by both $\mathbf{W}$ and $\mathbf{W}^T$. If I could calculate them individually, the shape of them are different ($m\times n$ and $n\times m$), I do not know how to merge two gradients together.

Answer (score 3):

Define two new variables and their differentials. $$\eqalign{
 Y &= (W^TW-I) &\implies dY &= dW^TW+W^TdW \cr
 z &= Yx     &\implies dz &= dY\,x \cr
}$$
Write the cost function in terms of these new variables.
Then find its differential and gradient. $$\eqalign{
 {\mathcal L} &= \tfrac{1}{2}z:z \cr
\cr
d{\mathcal L} &= z:dz \cr
 &= z:dY\,x \cr
 &= zx^T:(W^TdW+dW^TW) \cr
 &= (zx^T+xz^T):W^TdW \cr
 &= W(zx^T+xz^T):dW \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial W}
 &= W(zx^T+xz^T) \cr
 &= WYxx^T + Wxx^TY \cr
 &= W(W^TW-I)xx^T + Wxx^T(W^TW-I) \cr\cr
}$$
**NB:**  In some of the steps above, a colon is used to represent the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure how do you get $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{W}}$ from $d\mathcal{L} = \text{something} : d\mathbf{W}$ (maybe I am not aware of something really basic).